# Access exports on a module that is dynamically loaded through script tag?

Tags: javascript, module, script-tag

I load a module dynamically through a script tag (appending it to the DOM).

Now, HOW can I access this module?

```
    let script = document.createElement('script');
    
    ...
    
    script.onload = ( e ) => {
        // How can I access exports on the loaded script (ES module) here?
    };
```